# Adding a cover image to video shortcode

Tags: shortcode, thumbnails, video-player

I'm looking for a way to allow the user to add a cover image (a.k.a. thumbnail) to an internal video, uploaded to WordPress and embedded with the shortcode [video].

So far everything I came up to is adding or changing thumbnails to external videos.

Any ideas of appropriate hooks, plugins doing something similar or just advice on how to approach the problem are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Video Embed & Thumbnail Generator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/video-embed-thumbnail-generator/) already does what you are looking for.